# rotate a particle system in world scope unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I created [this particle (show in gif file)](https://gifyu.com/image/yDzw) ,by rotate particle I want to new particles spawn in new direction and rotation, but previous stay in their initial rotate and direction, and this is my particle settings:

[image: particle unity rotate direction]
[image: particle unity rotate direction]

Answer (score 0):

You should set Simulation Space to Local. World space particles aren't affected by Transform's rotation after they are emitted.

Answer (score 0):

In the particle system's Renderer settings, set the render mode to Mesh. Pick the Quad, or your custom mesh, and then set its render alignment to velocity.

Set the start speed to a non-zero value, such that the particle will now emit towards your transform rotation direction. (If you want to keep the particle stationary, but follows the rotation of your transform, set the particle speed to a extremely small value, like 0.0001)

Make sure the simulation space is set to "World"

With this, the particle rotation should now align with the velocity of your particle. To make the particle faces the camera, enable "3D start rotation" and adjust the rotation angles until it matches your desired orientation.

And now, you can change your particle system transform's rotation to change the orientation of your particle. Existing particles will stay at its original rotation, while newly emitted particles will orient towards the transform rotation.